# Confusion on Glassfish V3, Jboss, SOA supporting, WSO2(embeded Tomcat)

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss, glassfish, soa

I'm so confused for developing SOA applications in Java EE:

1. Can "Glassfish V3 Open Source Edition" support ESB(SOA)? I must add external module on it? if yes, is it open source too or not?    ---or--- if I want to use Glassfish I should buy the commercial Oracle Glassfish?
2. What is JBoss's behaviour? Is it possible to run ESB(SOA) on community JBoss open-source? What is Jboss SOA Platform? is it commercial? does have Jboss it's own commercial edition for enterprise SOA or with it's open-source editions we can do it?
3. What is WSO2? it works on which application-servers? I read somewhere it has it's own embedded tomcat server?!   unless Tomcat be a Java EE container?!!!!! of course not.

Please help me and bring me out of this confusion.

Answer (score 10):

Let me answer the WSO2 part- WSO2 has a set of products (all totally open source) which supports all aspects of SOA:

1. Writing and hosting services (App Server, Data Services Server, Business Rules Server etc.)
2. Mediating them in various ways (ESB), composing services to make more services (Business Process Server and Mashup Server)
3. Managing/governing them (Governance Registry, Identity Server, Business Activity Monitor).

WSO2 products use embedded Tomcat as its primary runtime for standalone execution but can also run within other app servers. See http://wso2.com/products for more info.

As someone else said SOA is a design paradigm not a choice of technology. Yes it is possible to do SOA without EJBs or Web services even .. CORBA for example.

Comment: of course, but application server should support JBI API or not? for example can I deploy an ESB on GLASSFISH v3? because it doesn't have JBI but v2 had JBI

Comment: Navid JBI is pretty much a dead technology. It was a framework the JCP defined for making something like ESBs but was really not very good and most people have ignored and gone past it. We (WSO2) never supported it and have no plans to either.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I know on this:

Glassfish v3 support EJB3.1 out of the box, you can use them per your pleassing
JBoss Application Server version 6 also support EJB 3.1 out of the box. As always, JBoss offers some custom non-spec config options, some of which intervene just a little bit over the EJB3.1 specs, but in all it's ok.
Yes, Tomcat by itself is not a full Java EE Application Server as it doesn't have (amongst others) an EJB Container. However one can be added to it via 3rd party modules

Comment: SOA is a design principle. Those are impelemented by the developer, not supported by the application server. The app server may support technologies that help SOA development such as EJB and WebServices. Both of these are supported by glassfish and jboss as (the latter in the form of the JAX-WS/JAX-RS specs)

Comment: so what is OpenESB, Glassfish ESB? in Glassfish v2 we have JBI but in V3 it seems move to fuji! or some thing like this

Comment: Yes, OpenESB just like Mule ESB supports certain technologies (a lot in this case) that enables you to have an Enterprise Serial bus architecture. This goes beyond SOA architecture and infact, depending on how you use it (reading files and sending emails and making reports in the DB - for example) may have nothing to do with SOA. Look, you're kindda jumbling notions here, I'm trying to explain. If you wanna rage, good luck to you. Here's an example of your missunderstanding: Tomcat can support SOA applications, even tho it has no EJB container. See what I mean?